# 3 Pesukim minimum per Aliyah

Tags: torah-reading, shiurim-measurements

Why is it that each aliyah for Krias Hatorah has to be 3 pesukim at minimum? I know that the minimum for an entire krias Hatorah on a weekday is 10 pesukim (with the exception of Purim being 9 pesukim), but why do the pesukim have to be split evenly amongst those called up?

Comment: The pesukim aren't necessarily split evenly; there are definitely unbalanced weekday readings.  Are you asking about the minimum or about even division?

Comment: Perhaps see Megillah 21b

Comment: @DoubleAA You mean 22a? It has this rule, but gives no reason.

Answer (score 6):

The [Talmud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud) states that this is to correspond to the three-fold division of Torah, Neviim, and Ketuvim:

**[Megillah 24a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=24&format=pdf)**

> הני ג' פסוקין כנגד מי אמר רב אסי כנגד תורה נביאים וכתובים
>
> What do these three verses represent? — R. Assi said: The Pentateuch, the Prophets,
> and the Hagiographa. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Megilah.pdf))

Most of the Codes simply cite the rule without mentioning the reason. Some of the commentaries to the Codes reference the Talmud's reasoning. However, [R. Mordechai Yaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Yoffe) in his Code provides a different reason. He simply says that the Sages assessed three verses to be the minimal amount that could be considered a significant reading for one person:

**[Levush O.C. 137:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14586&st=&pgnum=84)**

> ואין קורין עם כל אחד פחות מג' פסוקים שכן שיערו רבותינו ז"ל ג"כ שזה סגי לקרות קריאה חשובה לאיש אחד